# Measure exact clock cycles for a C/assembly program

Tags: performance, time, gdb

I need to measure the exact number of clock cycles it takes to execute a program. I already used the clock() function but it's values are dependent on system parameters. I could not figure out how to measure clock cycles using gdb. Are there any other tools that can be used for this?
Thank you.

Comment: Clock cycle measures are very arbitrary on a multi-threaded environment.  Even the kernel's scheduler doesn't track them and instead counts time slices.  It is actually a more reliable measure than to rely on external variables such as actual CPU efficiency, throttling, etc.  Perhaps sharing what your actual goal is might help you get more focused answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) performance counters to profile program execution. Basically you do

```
perf stat your_executable your_options
```

[Here](http://jvns.ca/blog/2014/05/13/profiling-with-perf/) are some quick examples, and [here](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) is a more detailed writeup.

Keep in mind that on modern CPUs, the clock cycles used to execute something will vary according to cache usage, internal scheduling/reordering etc. So if you want to spot profile bottlenecks, use the other options `perf` gives you.

Answer (score 0):

**Linux `perf_event_open` system call with `config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES`**

This syscall can be used if you can modify the source of the program. It can also measure results only for a given region of interest of the program.

Further details at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/how-to-get-the-cpu-cycle-count-in-x86-64-from-c/64898073#64898073

`perf_event_open.c`:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static long
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                    group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    long long count;
    int fd;

    uint64_t n;
    if (argc > 1) {
        n = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        n = 10000;
    }

    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
    // Don't count hypervisor events.
    pe.exclude_hv = 1;

    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

    /* Loop n times, should be good enough for -O0. */
    __asm__ (
        "1:;\n"
        "sub $1, %[n];\n"
        "jne 1b;\n"
        : [n] "+r" (n)
        :
        :
    );

    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
    read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));

    printf("%lld\n", count);

    close(fd);
}
```